# PHP - Swiftmailer using STARTTLS and self signed certificates

Tags: php, smtp, certificate, swiftmailer, self-signed

I'm trying to send an email with php and swiftmailer, using STARTTLS, but I'm getting a certificate error. I have root access to the SMTP server, and the certificate used is self-signed.
I'm using Debian on both machines (web server and smtp server)

`PHP message: PHP Warning:  stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in [..]/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php on line 97
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Unable to connect with TLS encryption' in [..]/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php:294`

Do I need to add my own certificate somewhere to get it accepted? Or is this some OpenSSL configuration error?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> ***Editor's note***: disabling SSL verification has **security implications.** Without verification of the authenticity of SSL/HTTPS connections, a malicious attacker can impersonate a trusted endpoint (such as GitHub or some other remote Git host), and you'll be vulnerable to a [Man-in-the-Middle Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).
>
> #### Be sure you fully understand the security issues before using this as a solution.

Swiftmailer has now been updated to include an option for this. It can now be solved using the `setStreamOptions` method from your `Swift_SmtpTransport` instance rather than editing the swift class.

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.server.com', 123, 'tls')
    ->setUsername('username')
    ->setPassword('password')
    ->setStreamOptions(array('ssl' => array('allow_self_signed' => true, 'verify_peer' => false)));
```

Comment: Where did you created those lines?

Comment: @WilliamLepinski You just make a call to setStreamOptions wherever it is in your code that you're creating the Swift_SmtpTransport instance. If you're not sure how to use Swift Mailer, see the example here: http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html Follow that example, but add the call to setStreamOptions from the Swift_SmtpTransport instance.

Comment: This is a worst thing you can do, disable all advantages of TLS security.

Answer (score 15):

I got the same problem using Swiftmailer in Laravel.

Looks like there is no option for this in Swiftmailer. Clean solution would be to add your own [root CA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) to your server and sign your mail server certificate with this CA. The certificate would be valid after this. See for example [this tutorial](http://datacenteroverlords.com/2012/03/01/creating-your-own-ssl-certificate-authority/).

> ***Editor's note***: disabling SSL verification has **security implications.** Without verification of the authenticity of SSL/HTTPS connections, a malicious attacker can impersonate a trusted endpoint (such as GitHub or some other remote Git host), and you'll be vulnerable to a [Man-in-the-Middle Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).
>
> #### Be sure you fully understand the security issues before using this as a solution.

Anyway, a quick dirty hack you should not use would be to edit `swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php`. In `_establishSocketConnection()` line 253 replace:

```
$options = array();
```

with something like this:

```
$options = array('ssl' => array('allow_self_signed' => true, 'verify_peer' => false));
```

This will change the [ssl options](http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php) of [stream_context_create()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) (a few lines below `$options`):

```
$this->_stream = @stream_socket_client($host.':'.$this->_params['port'], $errno, 
    $errstr, $timeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, stream_context_create($options));
```

Comment: @miken32 Thanks for the edit and the warnings. You can not be clear enough about this. Never disable this in production! Never commit code using this hack.

Comment: Actually I copied the text from an edit you'd made to another post lol. Was trying to find a duplicate target for this problem and kept on coming across all these "disable verification" answers. :(

Comment: @miken32 You made my day :D Not sure this text is really from me. Anyway, if you need to accept your selft signed certificate you have to create a root/CA certificate as source and add the root to your system. https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate

Answer (score 6):

> ***Editor's note***: disabling SSL verification has **security implications.** Without verification of the authenticity of SSL/HTTPS connections, a malicious attacker can impersonate a trusted endpoint (such as GitHub or some other remote Git host), and you'll be vulnerable to a [Man-in-the-Middle Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).
>
> #### Be sure you fully understand the security issues before using this as a solution.

You do not need to edit `/vendor` files. You can specify (undocumented) options in your `config/mail.php` file:

```
'stream' => [
    'ssl' => [
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ],
],
```

You can check it yourself in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/TransportManager.php` on line ~50:

```
...
if (isset($config['stream'])) {
    $transport->setStreamOptions($config['stream']);
}
...
```

Needless to say, circumventing peer verification has huge security implications (read vulnerabilities). I imagine this solution for some dev or local environment, never in production or even in an Internet/Publicly available app.

Answer (score 2):

> ***Editor's note***: disabling SSL verification has **security implications.** Without verification of the authenticity of SSL/HTTPS connections, a malicious attacker can impersonate a trusted endpoint (such as GitHub or some other remote Git host), and you'll be vulnerable to a [Man-in-the-Middle Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).
>
> #### Be sure you fully understand the security issues before using this as a solution.

For me, I had to add `$transport->setStreamOptions(array('ssl' => array('allow_self_signed' => true, 'verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false)));` to the Mailer.php file, see:

```
    /**
     * Returns the SMTP transport
     *
     * @return \Swift_SmtpTransport
     */
    protected function getSmtpInstance(): \Swift_SmtpTransport {
            $transport = new \Swift_SmtpTransport();
            $transport->setTimeout($this->config->getSystemValue('mail_smtptimeout', 10));
            $transport->setHost($this->config->getSystemValue('mail_smtphost', '127.0.0.1'));
            $transport->setPort($this->config->getSystemValue('mail_smtpport', 25));
            if ($this->config->getSystemValue('mail_smtpauth', false)) {
                    $transport->setUsername($this->config->getSystemValue('mail_smtpname', ''));
                    $transport->setPassword($this->config->getSystemValue('mail_smtppassword', ''));
                    $transport->setAuthMode($this->config->getSystemValue('mail_smtpauthtype', 'LOGIN'));
            }
            $smtpSecurity = $this->config->getSystemValue('mail_smtpsecure', '');
            if (!empty($smtpSecurity)) {
                    $transport->setEncryption($smtpSecurity);
            }
            $streamingOptions = $this->config->getSystemValue('mail_smtpstreamoptions', []);
            if (is_array($streamingOptions) && !empty($streamingOptions)) {
                    $transport->setStreamOptions($streamingOptions);
            }

            /* EDIT - allow self-signed mail cert */
            $transport->setStreamOptions(array('ssl' => array('allow_self_signed' => true, 'verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false)));
            /* EDIT end */

            return $transport;
    }
```

I got this from another link, can't find it now.

One think that I did extra to the other answers was to specify the `'verify_peer_name' => false`