# How to send mail with STARTTLS and self-signed certificate using Swiftmailer Library in PHP

Tags: php, email, ssl, swiftmailer

I want to use the SwiftMailer Class Library to send mails within a PHP Script.

The Mailserver provides the STARTTLS command and uses self-signed certificates.

The problem is that it seems to be a problem for SwiftMailer tgo send the mails.

If I simply use coee like this, to initialize the transport:

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance("server.example.com", 25, "tls")
->setUsername("user@example.com")
->setPassword("example");
```

This error is show:

```
Uncaught Swift_TransportException: Unable to connect with TLS encryption
```

I already search here and elsewhere. I found this thread here on StackOverflow: [PHP - Swiftmailer using STARTTLS and self signed certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26896265/php-swiftmailer-using-starttls-and-self-signed-certificates)

But when I add the mentioned method to the above code like this:

```
->setStreamOptions(array('ssl' => array('allow_self_signed' => true, 'verify_peer' => false)));
```

The block in full looks like this:

```
 $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance("server.example.com", 25, "tls")
->setUsername("user@example.com")
->setPassword("example")
->setStreamOptions(array('ssl' => array('allow_self_signed' => true, 'verify_peer' => false)));
```

I am getting this error:

```
Call to undefined method setStreamOptions
```

So it looks like the mentioned method got removed or renamed. I foun nothing about this in the SwiftMailer Documentation. There are only a few solutions mentioned on the web to patch the library. I don't checked these ways, because I don't want to modify the library code.

My SwiftMailer version is the actual `5.4.2`. Is there a way to solve this problem without patching the library and if it is necessary to do so, how this must be done.

Hope that someone can help me.

Best Regards

P.S. Hope I have done all right and my english is understandable. If there are questions please ask.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to this, but try upgrading to the latest swiftmailer version and it will solve your problem. I had version 5.4.1 and switched to 5.4.6 to get it working